# selected random item from dictionary exept the last one

Tags: javascript

please how i can selected random item from dictionary exept the last one in javascript?

```
var mydic={a:"1. xml",b:"2. xml"}
var cat = files_xml[Object. keys(files_xml) [Math. floor(Math. random() *Object. keys(files_xml). length)]] ;
```

Regards

Comment: What is the problem of using `Math.random()*(keys.length - 1)`?

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't this work, just don't go up to the `length` but one below

`var cat = files_xml[Object. keys(files_xml) [Math. floor(Math. random() * (Object. keys(files_xml). length - 1))]] ;`

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = Object.keys(mydic); //mydic is input dictionary, retrieving all the keys as array
mydic[keys[getRndInteger(0,keys.length-1)]] //obtaining key from keys array

//generating random integer using a function where min(included) and max (excluded)
function getRndInteger(min, max) {return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) ) + min;}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation about how this code answers the question